# Advanced Custom field thumbnail - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, field

I'm working on a website in wordpress, i'm trying to get the thumbnail from the advanced custom field of a post with this:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h1><?php the_field('custom_title'); ?></h1>
    <img src="<?php the_field('thumbnail'); ?>" alt="" />
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

The problem it's that when I load the website, the url the image gets looks like this:

```
<img src="5, , item_alt2, , , http://portfolio.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/item_alt2.jpg, Array">
```

So, as far as I see, the plugin it's working since looks for the image, but it loads an strange path to it, so it shows like "broken" image.

What i'm doing wrong?

```
 5, , item_alt2, , , http://portfolio.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/item_alt2.jpg, ArrayNULL
```

Comment: Just looking at it, and not knowing Wordpress that well, the way you're calling it with `the_field('thumbnail')` is returning a comma-delimited list in string form, with the thumbnail *possibly* at index #5 (zero being the first). So either you're passing the wrong value to the function, or you're expected to parse that somehow (`$thumb = explode(', ', the_field('thumbnail'));`, then use `$thumb[5]`), or something like that.

Comment: the_field('thumbnail') it's the way to call field of the function of the Advanced Custom Fields plugin

Comment: Does calling `the_field('custom_title');` return the proper value i.e. "My Custom Title"?

Comment: Yes, "the_field('custom_title');" returns the custom title I write in the post custom field box.

Comment: You really need to look at what you're getting and try to figure out why you're getting it. You should also have the source, so referring to it and finding why you're getting that specific result should also prove fruitful. You [can get the url from the returned function call](http://codepad.org/6BHNz1Mg), but that seems like a lot of work, so check first that you're doing it right.

Comment: Try checking if you haven't misspelled the field's name "thumbnail" in the html form and later in the processing code.

Comment: it's not mispelled, I have change it to other name and it happens the same, if you look, it is loading the image, so it's working... but the problem its that it puts a path to it, for example, if I change to a wrong name in my file, it doesn't even look for the path, that's the way I know it's working in some way

Comment: That's not a "path", it's a comma-delimited list.

Comment: Use this code to see what you're getting back: http://codepad.org/1PK1JGAw (Ignore the errors on codepad.) You are getting something, but you're getting back something you're not expecting (hence the suggestion of looking at the source code).

Comment: this it what the code returns: 5, , item_alt2, , , http://portfolio.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/item_alt2.jpg, ArrayNULL

Comment: Post it exactly from the source code into the question.

Comment: ok, I put it into the question

Comment: Actually, nevermind; the call itself is `echo`ing the result directly, so there's no return value (which I just realized).

Comment: What you show here doesn't seem to "suggest" you're doing anything wrong. However, it could be on the other end, when you save the `thumbnail` field, that it's saving a list of some sort. I would suggest investigating that side, not the output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the docs on Advanced Custom Fields;

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/field-types/image/

You are returning the value of the custom field as an object as per the example at the bottom;

```
Array
(
[id] => 540
[alt] => A Movie
[title] => Movie Poster: UP
[caption] => sweet image
[description] => a man and a baloon
[url] => http://localhost:8888/acf/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/up.jpg
[sizes] => Array
    (
        [thumbnail] => http://localhost:8888/acf/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/up-150x150.jpg
        [medium] => http://localhost:8888/acf/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/up-300x119.jpg
        [large] => http://localhost:8888/acf/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/up.jpg
        [post-thumbnail] => http://localhost:8888/acf/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/up.jpg
        [large-feature] => http://localhost:8888/acf/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/up.jpg
        [small-feature] => http://localhost:8888/acf/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/up-500x199.jpg
    )

)
```

Comment: Makes total sense (didn't see that in the docs), certainly makes sense of the printed value.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - I know, doesn't help that the text is virtually all greyed out! Looks like something that's been added in a later version ACF 3.3.7+

Comment: Yeah, it works haha, thank you very much!! Just have to change to return URL not object!

Comment: No worries - Jared and you did all the hard work :) Feel a bit guilty about that rep....but not that guilty ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. All you need to do is make sure you're not returning the image as an object. You do this when creating/editing the custom field. Just make sure you set the return value to image url:

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s3/sh/91d181ed-e9d6-4504-8ab5-cee7ae85d84f/dfc9944d16337e41fb6e7e30ed26bdb5

Then, you should be able to use this to display the image in your template:

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the customfield to return url. Looks lige it is set to object. You have 3 options to how to return an image.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow!  Note that this should probably be a comment rather than an answer.  By the way, what are the 3 options for returning an image?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just set custom field as IMAGE ID and use it like that

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('thumbnail'), 'sizename');
    <h1><?php the_field('custom_title'); ?></h1>
    <img src="' .$image[0]. '" alt="">
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```